# Google app script approval workflow where the approver decision is updated to the responses spreadsheet

Tags: workflow

I intent to build a workflow where the user enters the details in the google form and the user receives an acknowledgement email stating the details submitted and that he'll be notified soon about the decision. Simultaneously an email is send out to the approver to approve or reject the decision and the details submitted. After the approver clicks on the approve or reject an email is sent out to the user informing him about the decision. So far I have got this working. 
I want to add the approver decision to the spreadsheet i.e. the approver decision should be updated to the spreadsheet. Also there should be a remarks section for the approver to add remarks as to why he has approved or rejected the request.

```
function sendEmail(e){
  var Email_id = e.values[1];
  var Name = e.values[2];
  var batch = e.values[3];
  var section = e.values[4];
  var start_date = e.values[5];
  var end_date = e.values[6];
  var working_days = e.values[7];
  var organisation = e.values[8];
  var location = e.values[9];
  var skills_you_learn = e.values[10];
  var how_it_is_supporting_project = e.values[11];
  var fee = e.values[12];
  var proof_acceptance = e.values[13];

  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxgD3ySHDc8uG4omhW8VQuB5_4VABJLvevWftbl7i4w0Mpmpho/exec';
  var approve= url + '?approval=true' + '&reply='+Email_id;
  var reject= url + '?approval=false' + '&reply='+Email_id;
  var html ="<body>"+
    "<h3>Please review</h3><br/>" +
      "Name : " + Name + "<br/>"+
        "Email id : " + Email_id + "<br/>"+
          "Batch : " + batch + "<br/>"+
            "Section : " + section + "<br/>"+
              "Internship start date : " + start_date + "<br/>"+
                "Internship end date : " + end_date + "<br/>"+
                  "Organisation : " + organisation + "<br/>"+
                    "Location : " + location + "<br/>"+
                      "Skills you'll learn from the internship : " + skills_you_learn + "<br/>"+
                        "How the internship is supporting your final year project : " + how_it_is_supporting_project + "<br/>"+
                          "Fee : " + fee + "<br/>"+
                            "Proof of acceptance : " + proof_acceptance + "<br/>"+

                              "<a href=" + approve +">Approve</a><br/>" +
                                "<a href=" + reject +">Reject</a><br/>" +
              "<body/>";
  MailApp.sendEmail("zuhaatta10@gmail.com","Approval Request","What no html?",{htmlBody:html});

  var htmll ="<body>"+
           "<h3>You have submitted these details</h3>"+
             "Name : " + Name + "<br/>"+
        "Email id : " + Email_id + "<br/>"+
          "Batch : " + batch + "<br/>"+
            "Section : " + section + "<br/>"+
              "Internship start date : " + start_date + "<br/>"+
                "Internship end date : " + end_date + "<br/>"+
                  "Organisation : " + organisation + "<br/>"+
                    "Location : " + location + "<br/>"+
                      "Skills you'll learn from the internship : " + skills_you_learn + "<br/>"+
                        "How the internship is supporting your final year project : " + how_it_is_supporting_project + "<br/>"+
                          "Fee : " + fee + "<br/>"+
                            "Proof of acceptance : " + proof_acceptance + "<br/>"+

               "<h3>You'll be notified soon about the approval decision</h3>"+
                   "<body/>";
MailApp.sendEmail(Email_id,"Approval Request","What no html?",{htmlBody:htmll});

}
function doGet(e)
{
var app=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var answer =(e.parameter.approval=='true') ? 'Internship approved':'Internship not approved';

  var msg = 'Project review committee has ' + answer + ' your internship';
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply,"Internship Program",msg);  
  return app.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Do you have the solution for this ?